# How to show products in current table, and products from Shopify if unique

Tags: ruby, shopify

What I want:

If `@current_products` is empty then display `@new_products` from Shopify store.  But, if `@current_products` is not empty then display `@current_products` and also append any unique `@new_products` from Shopify store. I define a unique product by `product.id`.

What I have so far is this attempt:

```
 if @current_products.empty?            
   @new_products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all)
 elsif
   @current_products.each_with_index do |u, index|        
     if index == @current_products.size       
        @new_products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all)                  
        @new_products.delete_if do |product|
            if product.id.in?(@productIds)      
                true 
            end 
        end  
     end        
  end
 end
```

my erb then uses:

```
<% @current_products.each do |item| %>
      ...
<% end %>

<% @new_products.each do |item| %>
      ...
<% end %>
```

I know I am doing this wrong, but it does illustrate what I am trying to do. What's the preferred approach in this situation?

Comment: `@productIds` is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if i am wrong.

- You want to display **all** products if `@current_products` is empty.
- If `@current_products` is not empty, then you display the `@current_products` + all the remaining products in database, which is again **all** products. Only the order will be different.

#### Approach 1

If you want the two set of products in separate variables:

```
# Controller
@current_products = wherever_they_come_from
@new_products = ShopifyAPI::Product.where('id NOT IN (?)', @current_products.pluck(:product_id))

# View
<% @current_products.each do |product| %>
  <!-- Render product -->
<% end %>

<% @new_products.each do |product| %>
  <!-- Render product -->
<% end %>
```

#### Approach 2

**Not recommended unless `@current_products` and products from `ShopifyAPI::Product` have same attributes to be displayed**

If you **don't** want the two set of products in separate variables:

```
# Controller
@current_products = wherever_they_come_from
@current_products |= ShopifyAPI::Product.where('id NOT IN (?)', @current_products.pluck(:product_id))

# View
<% @current_products.each do |product| %>
  <!-- Render product -->
<% end %>
```

**Note:** I assume the `ShopifyAPI` models behave similar to `ActiveRecord` models in terms of query.

Comment: re: Approach 2. I am having issues with this line: `@current_products |= Shopify::Product.where('id NOT IN (?)', @current_products.pluck(:id))`

in `@current_products` the id is `product_id` and within `@new_products` the id is `id`.  I tried, `@new_products = Shopify::Product.where('id NOT IN (?)', @current_products.pluck(:product_id))` but get the error, `uninitialized constant ProductsController::Shopify`. I feel like we're pretty close thanks to you @Jagdeep Sing

Comment: oops, I mean Approach 1.

Comment: Okay, it's `ShopifyAPI`, not `Shopify`. I updated the answer.

Comment: I should've picked up on that. Now I receive the error: 'wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)' on that line.